# C# gRPC client side load balancing on port level

Tags: c#, https, grpc, grpc-c#

I have multiple instances of a gRPC server side implementation running on a single machine. Unfortunately I`m limited to windows as the serving machine. Therefore I bound the service instances(three in total) to separate ports on a shared host. It uses the GRPC.Core implementation.

On the client side I used the more modern Grpc.AspNetCore implementation of gRPC. The goal is to primarily use one service port and if not available fall back to the next service port. The idea is to do this by checking the health of an already existing `GrpcChannel` instance before executing an RPC and if not healthy create a new one. (The creation of a GrpcChannel is quite an expensive operation)

I tried the following to check the ConnectivityState of the channel and create a new one if not idling or ready:

```cs
if (!(_channel.State == ConnectivityState.Ready || _channel.State == ConnectivityState.Idle))
{
  //get next port from config and recreate GrpcChannel
}
```

Where I get an Invalid operation exception from the handler that the configured http handler does not support client side load balancing.

```
Exception was thrown by handler. Channel is configured with an HTTP transport doesn't support client-side load balancing or connectivity state tracking. The underlying HTTP transport must be a SocketsHttpHandler with no SocketsHttpHandler.ConnectCallback configured. The HTTP transport must be configured on the channel using GrpcChannelOptions.HttpHandler.
```

This is due to a custom HttpMessageHelper with a `ServerCertificateCustomValidationCallback` configured.

```
_channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(configuration.URL, new GrpcChannelOptions
{
  HttpHandler = customHttpHandler
});
```

Do I have to create a custom `HttpMessageHandler` to use the `GrpcChannel.State` fields to use client side load blancing? And if so how do I do that the best?
Otherwise I would check if I can connect to a tcp socket with the current channels port and if not so, create a new channel to the next port.

```
try
{
  var socket = new Socket(System.Net.Sockets.AddressFamily.InterNetwork, System.Net.Sockets.SocketType.Stream, System.Net.Sockets.ProtocolType.Tcp);
  socket.Connect(addr, 9443);
  socket.Close();
}
```

Which would at least give me some information if there is a tcp connection available.

---

EDIT: I found a solution - By switching from `HttpClientHandler` to `SocketsHttpHandler` when creating the Grpc channel by assigning an instance of `SocketsHttpHandler` to the `GrpcChannelOptions` `HttpHandler` field:

```
var socketHttpHandler = new SocketsHttpHandler();

_channel = GrpcChannel.ForAddress(configuration.URL, new GrpcChannelOptions
{
  HttpHandler = socketHttpHandler
});
```

Afterwards you can use `_channel.State` to get the connections state and proceed from there.

```cs
if (!(_channel.State == ConnectivityState.Ready || _channel.State == ConnectivityState.Idle))
{
  //get channels health
}
```

Comment: Port 443 is HTTPS, not TCP.  HTTP uses TCP as the transport layer.  You must have a listener on server for each port you are connecting.  Port 443 is the standard port number for HTTPS but you can use other unused port numbers.  If you use a different port number make sure it is not blocked by a virus checker and not being used by another application/protocol.

Comment: @jdweng - yes, this last code snippet was just an example on how this could look like, unfortunately it doesn’t check for the health of the serving instance :/

Comment: What criteria do you want to use for health?  Maybe Ping?

Comment: @jdweng to be honest, I would prefer to check the ConnectivityState of the channel. But thats not possible with a custom HttpMessageHandler - not as far as I know, maybe someone knows how to implement one.

Comment: What you want to do is to check the HTTP port number is listening on a remote machine.  Only thing I found is using Netstat.  See https://www.reddit.com/r/sysadmin/comments/l76ycq/netstat_on_remote_computer_on_domain/

Comment: @jdweng I found a working solution - By switching from `HttpClientHandler` to `SocketsHttpHandler` when creating the Grpc channel by assigning an instance of `SocketsHttpHandler` to the `GrpcChannelOptions` `HttpHandler` field. Afterwards you can get the channels state and proceed from there. But thank you very much, I really appreciate your afford!

Comment: You are creating a new connection and getting status of the new connection.  New connection will fail if server is not listening so indirectly you are getting the state of the listener.  You are not directly getting the state.

Comment: Yes @jdweng, you are right. I tested a reference implementation and can confirm your suggestion. I will implement a small preflight request, that checks if there is a tcp port bound and listening to the requested port. That I tried and seems to work. I will update this question as soon as I have some data available after load testing.